# Unexpected incorrect result after unixtime conversion in sparksql

Tags: scala, dataframe, unix-timestamp

I have a dataframe with content like below:

```
scala> patDF.show
+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|patientID|   name|dateOtBirth|lastVisitDate|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|     1001|Ah Teck| 1991-12-31|   2012-01-20|
|     1002|  Kumar| 2011-10-29|   2012-09-20|
|     1003|    Ali| 2011-01-30|   2012-10-21|
+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

all the columns are string

I want to get the list of records with **lastVisitDate** falling in the range of format of **yyyy-mm-dd** and now, so here is the script:

```
patDF.registerTempTable("patients") 
val results2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(lastVisitDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) between '2012-09-15' and current_timestamp() order by lastVisitDate")
results2.show()
```

It gets me nothing, presumably, there should be records with patientID of 1002 and 1003.

So I modified the query to:

```
val results3 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(lastVisitDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')), * FROM patients")
results3.show()
```

Now I get:

```
+-------------------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|                _c0|patientlD|   name|dateOtBirth|lastVisitDate|
+-------------------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|2012-01-20 00:01:00|     1001|Ah Teck| 1991-12-31|   2012-01-20|
|2012-01-20 00:09:00|     1002|  Kumar| 2011-10-29|   2012-09-20|
|2012-01-21 00:10:00|     1003|    Ali| 2011-01-30|   2012-10-21|
+-------------------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

If you look at the first column, you will see all the months were somehow changed to 01

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for `year-month-day` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
val patDF = Seq(
  (1001, "Ah Teck", "1991-12-31", "2012-01-20"),
  (1002, "Kumar", "2011-10-29", "2012-09-20"),
  (1003, "Ali", "2011-01-30", "2012-10-21")
)toDF("patientID", "name", "dateOtBirth", "lastVisitDate")

patDF.createOrReplaceTempView("patTable")

val result1 = spark.sqlContext.sql("""
  select * from patTable where to_timestamp(lastVisitDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    between '2012-09-15' and current_timestamp() order by lastVisitDate
""")

result1.show
// +---------+-----+-----------+-------------+
// |patientID| name|dateOtBirth|lastVisitDate|
// +---------+-----+-----------+-------------+
// |     1002|Kumar| 2011-10-29|   2012-09-20|
// |     1003|  Ali| 2011-01-30|   2012-10-21|
// +---------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

You can also use DataFrame API, if wanted:

```
val result2 = patDF.where(to_timestamp($"lastVisitDate", "yyyy-MM-dd").
    between(to_timestamp(lit("2012-09-15"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), current_timestamp())
  ).orderBy($"lastVisitDate")
```